# Using Abstract Classes and Interfaces with ORM in Symfony, Interface not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a project which uses three different databases the first one is the main database which I can make changes to the second two belong to different projects but I need to access data in them. The following is a simplified directory structure.

Src

- AppBundle

  - Entity

    - BusinessUnitsFox
    - DriverMax
    - VehicleFox
  - Model

    - BusinessUnitInterface
    - UDODriverInterface
    - VehicleInterface
- FoxBundle

  - Entity

    - BusinessUnits
    - Vehicle
- MaxBundle

  - Entity

    - DriverMax

Below are the files for the abstract class and interface for BusinessUnits the Vehicle and Driver are similar.

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Model/BusinessUnitInterface.php

namespace AppBundle\Model;

interface BusinessUnitInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString();
}
```

The Abstract Class

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FoxBundle\Entity\BusinessUnit as BaseBU;
use AppBundle\Model\BusinessUnitInterface;

 /**
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\Table(name="business_unit_fox")
  */
class BusinessUnitFox extends BaseBU implements BusinessUnitInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    * @see \AppBundle\Model\BusinessUnitInterface::__toString()
    */
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getId();
    }
}
```

config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: maxdb
        connections:
            maxdb:
                # ...
            foxdb:
                # ...
            max2db:
                # ...
    orm:
        resolve_target_entities:
            AppBundle\Model\VehicleInterface: AppBundle\Entity\VehicleFox
            AppBundle\Model\UDODriver: AppBundle\Entity\DriverMax
            AppBundle\Model\BusinessUnit: AppBundle\Entity\BusinessUnitFox
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: maxem
        entity_managers:
            maxem:
                connection: maxdb
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: 
                    BWTCalendarBundle: ~
                    BWTFMBundle: ~
                    BWTHealthCheckBundle: ~
                    BWTSkytrackBundle: ~
                    BWTTelematicsBundle: ~
            foxem:
                connection: foxdb
                mappings:
                    FoxBundle: ~
            max2em:
                connection: max2db
                mappings:
                    MaxBundle: ~
```

When I do A SQL call I get the following error

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'telematics.vehicle_fox' doesn't exist`

So I ran `doctrine:schema:update` and got the following error

`[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
Class 'AppBundle\Model\BusinessUnitInterface' does not exist`

Is there anything that I am missing?

Is it possible to declare a OneToMany relationship from the abstract class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the Interface suffix for UDODriverInterface and BusinessUnitInterface. You can follow the [Symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) to do your mapping on Abstract classes and Interfaces

```
resolve_target_entities:
            AppBundle\Model\VehicleInterface: AppBundle\Entity\VehicleFox
            AppBundle\Model\UDODriverInterface: AppBundle\Entity\DriverMax
            AppBundle\Model\BusinessUnitInterface: AppBundle\Entity\BusinessUnitFox
```

Note also with the current declaration, your AppBundle\Entity\BusinessUnitFox class is not abstract.

Comment: thanks @OlivierC I have been using that link but must have been staring at this for too long to miss that.